# Confusion about Robbins-Monro algorithm in Bishop PRML

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, gradient-descent, optimization, stochastic-approximation

This is basically how Robbins-Monro is presented in chapter 2.3 of Bishop's PRML book (from his [slides](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiR6Zq7zLvRAhVl6IMKHdwKD5wQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fresearch%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F05%2Fprml-slides-2.pptx&usg=AFQjCNE7ETemDTEr5sDRUGBEq3ZR2Pb9AA&sig2=QxAsvjs62IaU6h3O-4-OjQ&bvm=bv.143423383,d.amc)):
[image]

In the general update equation,
$$ \theta^{(N)} = \theta^{(N-1)} - \alpha_{N-1}z(θ^{(N-1)}) $$

> $z(θ^{(N)})$ is an observed value of $z$ when $θ$ takes the value
> $θ^{(N)}$.

What got me confused is the introduction of the data variable $x$ into the equation in the last slide, particularly how $z$ now depends on $x$ (and $\theta$).

From the second to last equation, I can see that  $z(\theta)$ should take the form:
$$ z(\theta)= \frac{\partial}{\partial θ} [ - \text{ln} p(x | \theta) ]  $$

But it's not clear to me how $z(θ^{(N-1)})$ becomes $\frac{\partial}{\partial θ^{(N-1)}} [ - \text{ln} p(x_N | \theta^{(N-1)})]$
in the last equation:

$$\theta^{(N)} = \theta^{(N-1)} - \alpha_{N-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial θ^{(N-1)}} [ - \text{ln} p(x_N | \theta^{(N-1)})] $$

Why is $x_N$ used for the likelihood instead of $x_{N-1}$, since $\theta^{(N-1)}$ is also used? Is $x$ considered given/fixed or is it a random variable?

And with any correctly chosen $\alpha_N$, am I garuanteed to reach a maximum likelihood estimate after iterating through the $N$ data points (i.e. is it an "online" algorithm, or do I need to process all the data several epochs for before convergence)?

Comment: I guess you need to observe $x_N$ data point to estimate $\theta_N$

Answer (score 0):

Following Bishop PRML section 2.3.5, given a joint distribution, $p(z,\theta)$, Robbins-Monro is an algorithm for iterating to the root of the regression function, $f(\theta) = E[z|\theta]$. To apply it to find the true mean $\mu$, we let $\mu_{ML}$ play the role of $\theta$, and let $z=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_{ML}} [\text{ln} p(x | \mu_{ML};\sigma^2) ]=-(x-\mu_{ML})/\sigma^2$.

Then the Robbins-Monro iteration

$\mu_{ML}^{(N)}=\mu_{ML}^{(N-1)}-a_{N-1}z(\mu_{ML}^{(N-1)})$

reproduces (2.26) with $a_N=\sigma^2/N$.

Note that $p(z|\mu_{ML};\sigma^2)=N(z|(\mu_{ML}-\mu)/\sigma^2; \sigma^{-2})$ so that the regression function, $f(\mu_{ML})=E[z|\mu_{ML}]$ meets the criteria for RM iteration to a root: $E[z|\mu_{ML}]>0$ when $\mu_{ML}-\mu>0$ and $f(\mu_{ML}=\mu)=0$.

Note that, in the earlier printings, there are many [errata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf) for this section 2.3.5, key among them is that $\theta$ corresponds to $\mu_{ML}$ (not to $\mu$) as indicated in Figure 2.11.

The $x_i$ are iid (, but the $z_i$ are not, they are converging to 0 via the Robbins-Monro). So it's therefore no problem to use $x_N$ instead of $x_{N-1}$, likewise one can cycle through and use $x_i$ as $x_{i+N}$ to generate $z_{i+N}$.